# Sum two column per two column in a dataset -Python

Tags: python

I have a dataset and I would like to merge the two first column and the two next and so on.

[image: Input]

[image: Output expected]

Comment: Can you post an example of the dataset and the results expected?

Comment: How do you mean by "merging columns". Can you please add a snippet or example of input and expected output ?

Comment: I would like to sum the first two column of my dataset then the next two:

Comment: @Dodo3 Just `df['first_col'] + df['second_col']` would sum first two columns. Do the same for the next two columns.

Comment: @Codelt Yes of course I could do it but I have 200 columns :(

Comment: @Dodo3 `for i in range(0, 200, 2):    df.iloc[i] + df.iloc[i+1]`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your column names there for I have put random names into your columns. When you assign this dataset to `pandas dataframe` I assume your dataframe variable is `df`

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:<your dataset>
```

- First get sum of first two columns and assign it into single column

```
In [3]:df['Total1'] = df['first_column'] + df['Second_column']
```

- Then we get sum of Third and forth column and assign it into another single column

```
In [4]:df['Total2'] = df['Third_column'] + df['Fourth_column']
```

- All are complete then you can run this

```
In [5]:df
Out[5]:<your dataset with Total1 and Total2 columns>
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: If this method work for you, you can accept this answer. Then other users can get their answers from here.